# Kernel of conjugate transpose multiplication

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to prove that above $\Bbb C$ it is true that $\mathrm{Ker}(T)=\mathrm{Ker}(T^* T)$ where $T^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $T$... Is it actually true? 
How can I prove it? (One side of containing is obvious, yet I couldn't find a way to prove that the dimensions are equal)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x \in \ker (T^*T)$, then 
$$ \|Tx\|^2 = (Tx, Tx) = (x, T^*Tx) = 0 $$
so $Tx = 0$. As you wrote, the other inclusion is obvious.